# logging not creating file for next day instead appending info in old date log file

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to maintain a log using logging module but once I start the script it keeps on appending in the current date log file instead of creating new file for next day. Script  is running 24 hrs.I am not sure how can I handle that.

MY code:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
import time
import logging

LogDirectory="D:\\Python_Collateral_Validation_Service\\Logs"

while True:
    logfile=LogDirectory+"\\"+str(date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")).replace("/", "")+".log"
    print("log file name := ",logfile)
    logging.basicConfig(filename = logfile, level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    logging.info("CollateralValidation-> CSV File Not Present")
    time.sleep(90)
```

print statement:

```
log file name :=  D:\Python_Collateral_Validation_Service\Logs\06012022.log
log file name :=  D:\Python_Collateral_Validation_Service\Logs\07012022.log
PS D:\Alok\CR06645_PythonCode_phase2>
```

logfile was generated only for 06012022 but it was writing for 07012022 as well .where in expected was **07012022.log** which did not get generated.

**Output of 06012022.log**

```
2022-01-06 16:11:53,480 CollateralValidation-> CSV File Not Present
2022-01-06 16:12:26,580 CollateralValidation-> CSV File Not Present
2022-01-06 16:15:00,987 CollateralValidation-> CSV File Not Present
2022-01-07 16:16:29,998 CollateralValidation-> CSV File Not Present
```

**07012022 did not get generated for above last line**

Comment: Make your code simpler: `strftime("%d/%m/%Y")).replace("/", "")` -> `strftime("%d%m%Y")`?

Comment: Most people want their log files sorted by date, so %Y%m%d is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured

and in the same sentence there's a proposed solution

> unless the keyword argument force is set to True.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `while True :` and just schedule the script to run periodically on task scheduler. There is an option to do that.

Why I like this method :

- the file name for logging is evaluated at each run so you always get the right file name for the day. Script does not need complex logic to handle date change.
- if you schedule the task correctly (run on computer start option)you will not have to worry about running the script on the computer start.
- a long running script is more likely to crash / act awkwardly than a script that run, do its job and stop periodically

This is not a pure python solution but it will work reliably.

Finally, a word of advice : use "%Y%m%d" for your log file names format. This will allow far better file ordering when navigating through your log files.